# Пользовательские переменные mysql java

Tags: java, mysql

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в запросе:

```
String query2 = "select message from messages_type WHERE str ='qwe'"
```

вместо `str = 'qwe'` использовать `str = var_qwe`, где `var_qwe` - моя локальная переменная типа `String`, используемая в программе?

Comment: Наберите в гугле - mysql bind variable. И отформатируйте фрагменты кода в вопросе.

Comment: Из какого языка и фреймворка вы планируете обращаться к MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```
String var_qwe = "some text";
String query2 = "select message from messages_type WHERE str ='" + var_qwe + "'";
```

Comment: Спасибо, сработало!

Comment: @prometey_qwe отметьте, пожалуйста, вопрос как правильный галочкой напротив для тех, кто наткнется на тему в дальнейшем.